# Completing square for a sphere

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I was studying for triple integrals in spherical coordinates and got stuck because of an algebra bump.

$$x^2+y^2+z^2=2az $$ and I need to get something like $$ a^2=x^2+y^2+z^2$$ The answer for the first equation is $$x^2+y^2+(z-a)^2=a^2$$ and I have no idea how we get this form. I found out that it's called completing square which I've heard first time in my life. I haven't encountered it in my school career weirdly.

I found some videos about quadratic equations but I couldn't really use it for my sphere. Can someone show me the steps how we get it?

Answer (score 2):

Take the first equation, $x^2 +y^2 +z^2=2az$ and substract the RHS to get $x^2 +y^2 +z^2-2az=0$. Now add $a^2$ to both sides yielding $x^2 +y^2 +z^2 -2az +a^2=a^2$, note that $x^2 +y^2 +z^2 -2az +a^2=x^2 +y^2 +(z-a)^2$. This gives you your last equation.

Comment: When I add $a^2$, I am 'completing the square'; the square being $(z-a)^2=z^2-2az+a^2$  (it is 'incomplete' without the $a^2$ piece).

Comment: omg I don't know this has a special name. thank you!